# Expect script reading commands from file

Tags: shell, cygwin, expect, mkdir

I'm trying to write an expect script that reads commands from a file and executes them, as explained in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662391/read-file-into-string-and-do-a-loop-in-expect-script). Here is my script called `script.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set f [open "script_cmds.txt"]
set cmds [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach cmd $cmds {
    spawn cmd 
}

expect eof
close
```

And the file `script_cmds.txt`, situated in the same folder, looks like this:

```
mkdir cmdlisttest1
mkdir cmdlisttest2
```

To compile and run the script on cygwin I use

```
chmod +x script.sh
d2u script.sh
./script.sh
```

The output I get reads

```
spawn cmd
spawn cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\cygwin\home\user>
```

and then it stops there without exiting. The folders `cmdlisttest1` and `cmdlisttest2` are not created.

I'm fairly new to expect scripts; can anyone spot the mistake(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing `spawn cmd` instead of `spawn $cmd`.
With `$cmd` you're reading the value stored in the variable `cmd` and that's what you want.

Comment: Apparently that's a line-breaks problem. When you execute `d2u`, does it make the conversion *in place*? I suggest you `tr -d '\r' < script.sh > script_unix.sh` instead of `d2u`, and then execute: `./script_unix.sh`

Comment: I still can't quite get it to work; since the question has changed I posted a new topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677866/expect-script-not-able-to-read-mkdir-from-file-and-execute