# Expect script not able to read mkdir from file and execute

Tags: shell, cygwin, expect, mkdir

This is a continuation of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668144/expect-script-reading-commands-from-file); since it's a different question from the OP I'm making a new topic. I have an expect script I can't get working that is supposed to read commands from a file and execute them. This is the script itself, called `script.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set prompt {\$\s*$}
set f [open "script_cmds_u.txt"]
set cmds [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach cmd $cmds {
    spawn $cmd
    expect -re $prompt
}

expect eof
close
```

The file script_cmds.txt looks like this:

```
mkdir cmdlisttest1
mkdir cmdlisttest2
```

To run the script I use

```
tr -d '\r' < testpswd2.sh > testpswd2_u.sh
tr -d '\r' < script_cmds.txt > script_cmds_u.txt
chmod +x testpswd2_u.sh
./testpswd2_u.sh
```

Doing it like this I get the following error: `couldn't execute "mkdir cmdlisttest1": no such file or directory`.

So I try a number of changes:

- Change it to `send $cmd` in the loop. This changes the output to `mkdir cmdlisttest1couldn't compile regular expression pattern: invalid escape \ sequence`. I also try this with `\n` and `\r` after the commands in `script_cmds.txt`.
- Remove the `expect -re $prompt` in the loop. Then I get `mkdir cmdlisttest1mkdir cmdlisttest2` and it hangs there.
- Put a `spawn "\n"` after the `send $cmd`; then I get

  `mkdir cmdlisttest1spawn`

  `couldn't execute "`

  `": no such file or directory`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is due to `spawn` is taking the whole string (e.g.: `mkdir cmdlisttest1`) as a command without arguments.

Try instead with [argument expansion](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9) (thanks [@glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman)):

```
foreach cmd $cmds {
    spawn {*}$cmd
    expect -re $prompt
}
```

---

Another option:

```
foreach cmd $cmds {
    spawn [lindex $cmd 0] [lrange $cmd 1 [llength $cmd]]
    expect -re $prompt
}
```

With `[lindex $cmd 0]` you'll get **mkdir**;
With `[lrange $cmd 1 [llength $cmd]]`, the arguments (e.g. **cmdlisttest1**).

> [`lindex`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcltutorial/html/Tcl14.html) **list index**
>       Returns the index'th item from the list. Note: lists start from 0, not 1, so the first item is at index 0, the second item is at index 1, and so on.
>
> [`lrange`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcltutorial/html/Tcl16.html) **list first last**
>       Returns a list composed of the first through last entries in the list. If first is less than or equal to 0, it is treated as the first list element. **If last is end or a value greater than the number of elements in the list, it is treated as the end**. If first is greater than last then an empty list is returned.