# How to send commands stored in a file when using Expect

Tags: bash, shell, unix, while-loop, expect

I'm writing a script that will eventually execute a list of commands on a switch (via SSH). These commands are stored in a file and the number of commands will vary

However, I'm not sure how this can be done using Expect. I know Expect can use a while loop, but I can't find a clear example. can someone here help?

```
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@$switch
expect "*Enter password for admin\:"
send "password\r"
expect "*#"
send "????"
```

there should be a while loop that reads line by line from a file called "commands" that looks like this

```
command 1
command 2
command 3
...
```

Comment: What switch platform are you using?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17697484/478288) address your question?

Comment: @chrisaycock I think he's trying to do the same thing I'm doing, however, on multiple hosts. I will try and let you know.

Comment: @MattH Debian (latest).

Comment: Your switch is running Debian?

Comment: @MattH no it's an Extreme Networks switch. My script is running on a Debian machine. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Extreme Networks XOS has an XML API. You can use this for executing arbitrary commands. See the [ExtremeXOS XML API Developer Guide](http://extrcdn.extremenetworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/ExtremeXOS_XML_API_Developers_Guide.pdf) which is listed on the [support documentation](http://www.extremenetworks.com/support/documentation) page.

Managing switches by expect-scripting their CLIs is often erratic and error prone, I'd recommend that you avoid doing so if possible.