# how to give number of input to console one by one from file consists of single word in each line in UNIX SHELL SCRIPT

Tags: shell, unix, input

i have a file consists of each word in a line.

eg:- file consists of

```
 9/20/16
 11:00
 vamsi
```

I want to make each line as an input to console when ever it waits for input 
eg:- console is like

PLEASE ENTER TODAY'S DATE : 9/20/16

PLEASE ENTER CURRENT TIME : 11:00

PLEASE ENTER USER NAME : vamsi

It should take input from the file line by line like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need [Expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). It's commonly used to [respond to interactive prompts](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts) in shell programs [based on file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662391/read-file-into-string-and-do-a-loop-in-expect-script).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use that file as input:

```
program < file
```

For example, I want to select my timezone using the `tzselect` tool.
For my timezone, I need to enter

```
7
16
2
1
```

Saving this contents into `input.txt`, I can run `tzselect` with

```
tzselect < input.txt
```

This gives the same output as if the values have been typed in manually.

Comment: i want to give input to a running script from a file.

Comment: Yes. That was your question. My answer responds to that question. Stack Overflow is not a chat or forum. If you have a new question, ask a new question. If you feel your question has been misunderstood, *edit and improve* your question. Please be clear and precise. Your comment adds no new information and thus does not fit to the format of Stack Overflow.