# Looping through Interactive installer using expect

Tags: expect

I am trying to automate screen input of an interactive installer using expect and would like to use a loop which loops through lines of an answer file as input for part of the installer.

The installer has several sections to it, some of which are easily handled with simple expect/send responses. However there is a section in the installer which loops asking for data until you press a key to finish input. Then the rest of the installer continues.

The looping section looks like this on screen:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please enter ID details:
Please select an option: [A]dd [D]elete [I]mport [E]xport [F]inish =>A

Path: /opt/scanner/REF1/dump 
ID: REF1


Please enter ID details:
Please select an option: [A]dd [D]elete [I]mport [E]xport [F]inish =>A

Path: /opt/scanner/REF2/dump 
ID: REF2

Please select an option: [A]dd [D]elete [I]mport [E]xport [F]inish =>F

Rest of installer....
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Part of my expect script for the above looks like this:

```
expect -exact "Please select an option: \[A\]dd \[D\]elete \[I\]mport \[E\]xport \[F\]inish =>"
send -- "A\r"

expect -exact "Path: "
send -- "/opt/scanner/REF1/dump"
expect -exact "/opt/scanner/REF1/dump"
send -- "\r"


expect -exact "Please select an option: \[A\]dd \[D\]elete \[I\]mport \[E\]xport \[F\]inish =>"
send -- "A\r"

expect -exact "Path: "
send -- "/opt/scanner/REF2/dump"
expect -exact "/opt/scanner/REF2/dump"
send -- "\r"

expect -exact "Please select an option: \[A\]dd \[D\]elete \[I\]mport \[E\]xport \[F\]inish =>"
send -- "F\r"
```

Please excuse the verbosity as I have not been using expect long. This works but is not very efficient.

Ideally the answer file contains the REF1, REF2, until EOF (one per line) and a loop to read each line and send to the screen.

I have seen this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662391/read-file-into-string-and-do-a-loop-in-expect-script) but not sure how this fits in with the above.

I have been playing around with this Tcl code which may form a solution?

```
puts "/opt/scanner/$LINE/dump"
puts "$LINE"
```

Where $LINE is REF1, REF2 from the answer file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first things to do to reduce the verbosity are: put the prompt into a variable; send the carriage return with the path.

```
set prompt "Please select an option: \[A\]dd \[D\]elete \[I\]mport \[E\]xport \[F\]inish =>"

expect -exact $prompt
send -- "A\r"
expect -exact "Path: "
send -- "/opt/scanner/REF1/dump\r"

expect -exact $prompt
send -- "A\r"
expect -exact "Path: "
send -- "/opt/scanner/REF2/dump\r"
send -- "\r"

expect -exact $prompt
send -- "F\r"
```

We could put this into a loop, but it adds some complexity

```
set refs [list "REF1" "REF2"]
set count 0
expect $prompt {
    if {$count == 2} {
        send -- "F\r"
    } else {
        send -- "A\r"
        expect -exact "Path: "
        set ref [lindex $refs $count]
        send -- "/opt/scanner/$ref/dump\r"
        incr count
        exp_continue
    }
}
```

The `exp_continue` command "loops" back to the "outer" expect command.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Glenn - it's much appreciated. I should have made it a bit clearer with regards to the directory "REF". They are not necessarily in incremental order but could be totally random and unrelated strings. That's why I thought it would be better to read from a file.

Comment: Updated my answer to store the refs in a list, and the expect loop can look them up.