# Read lines for variables in Expect Script

Tags: shell, unix, expect

I'm trying to write an expect script (for the first time) and what I'm trying to do is read lines from a text file (input.txt) and assign them as specific variables in an expect script. My text file takes input from a web app and will have exactly 5 lines (5 variables for my script). Since I already know what each line represents, I want to create specifically-named variables for them..

line 1 is $user

line 2 is $password

line 3 is $logs1

line 4 is $logs2

line 5 is $containerName

I've looked at this link: [Read file into String and do a loop in Expect Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662391/read-file-into-string-and-do-a-loop-in-expect-script) and see that they used

```
    set f [open "host.txt"]
    set hosts [split [read $f] "\n"]
    close $f
```

to collect from a file of all host names and just iterate through them in a loop but how do I name each line differently according to what the line represents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward method is just:

```
set f [open "host.txt"]
gets $f user
gets $f password
gets $f logs1
gets $f logs2
gets $f containerName
close $f
```

For more background see https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl24.html

Comment: An alternative to 5 gets commands is `lassign [split [read -nonewline $f] \n] user password logs1 logs2 containerName`

Comment: Well if you want to be minimalist you could compress the 5 gets commands into `foreach v {user password logs1 logs2 containerName} {gets $f $v}` but for the OP I suspect simple and straightforward is best.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `hosts` is a list of items. You access the individual items using the [lindex](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/lindex.htm) command. Example:

```
set user [lindex $hosts 0]
set passwd [lindex $hosts 1]
```